# How to Store NSPopUpButton TitleOfSelectedItem to Core Data Model Field?

Tags: swift, macos, core-data

I have created the following view controller and wired up the controls in my storyboard to it.

```
import Foundation
import CoreData
import AppKit

protocol SubmissionViewControllerDelegate {
  func controller(_controller: SubmissionViewController, 
                  didAddSubmissionWithID profileID: Int64)
}

class SubmissionViewController : ViewController {
  @IBOutlet var profileIDComboBox: NSPopUpButton!
  var profileSelectedValue: String!
  @IBOutlet var transcriptTypeComboBox: NSPopUpButton!
  var transcriptTypeSelectValue: String!
  @IBOutlet var submissionTypeComboBox: NSPopUpButton!
  var submissionTypeSelectValue: String!
  @IBOutlet var transcriptionTurnaroundComboBox: NSPopUpButton!
  var turnaroundSelectValue: String!
  @IBOutlet var persistentNoteComboBox: NSPopUpButton!
  var persistentNoteSelectValue: String!
  @IBOutlet var notesTextField: NSTextField!
  @IBOutlet var batchIdentifierTextField: NSTextField!
  @IBOutlet var languageInAudioComboBox: NSPopUpButton!
  var languageSelectValue: String!
  @IBOutlet var addResultViewButton: NSButton!
  @IBOutlet var submissionFiles: NSTableView!

  var delegate: SubmissionViewControllerDelegate?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  @IBAction func save(_ sender: Any) {
    guard case profileIDComboBox.titleOfSelectedItem = 
               profileSelectedValue else { return }
    guard case transcriptTypeComboBox.titleOfSelectedItem = 
               transcriptTypeSelectValue else { return }
    guard let delegate = delegate else { return }

    delegate.controller(self, didAddSubmissionWithID: 
                        profileSelectedValue)
  }
}
```

I now want to store the `titleOfSelectedItem` from each `NSPopUpButton` in my Core Data Submission model. However, when I set the variables to be strings, I receive the error as follows:

> Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type '_OptionalNilComparisonType'

How do I accomplish this task?

Comment: Which line(s) of code are causing that error message?

Comment: @TomHarrington The errors are caused by the guard statements in the save function.